# Which methods will raise NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception, null

I'm using Objective-c and cocoa api for a while. But I don't know which methods in cocoa apis will raise NSInvalidArgumentException if I pass nil to the parameters.

How can I get the list that all methods will raise NSInvalidArgumentException and which parameter can not be nil. The offical documents is not very clear sometimes and the informations are decentralized.

Like this method

> NSData's -writeToURL:options:error:

I know the first parameter can not be nil or it will crash, but the document never tell me that information. How can I know in all Cocoa APIs, which methods can't not receive nil parameter and will raise NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: So the real question is primarily "Which API function arguments accept nil values?" ?

Comment: Why do you need the whole list?  Can't you look at the individual documentation pages for any classes you use to understand the argument usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the Swift declaration. If it's not an optional, then `nil` is not allowed. If it's a regular optional (`?`), then `nil` is explicitly allowed. If it's an implicitly-unwrapped optional (`!`), then you don't know. For example, for the method you referred to, `-[NSData writeToURL:options:error:]`, the Swift declaration is:

```
func writeToURL(_ aURL: NSURL,
          options mask: NSDataWritingOptions,
        error errorPtr: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
```

The type `NSURL` (instead of `NSURL?` or `NSURL!`) indicates that `nil` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Apple documentation for a method, if nil is accepted for a parameter that will be specified otherwise it is required.

The one place you should not pass nil even when it would be accepted is for error reference parameters: errors should not be ignored.